# Targeting more specific web browser users (versions)

Tags: php, html, browser, web

Is there anyway of targeting browser version users?

Right now I currently have:

```
<?php
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== FALSE)
                    $browser = 'ie';
    elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox') !== FALSE)
                    $browser = 'firefox';
    elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari') !== FALSE)
                    $browser = 'safari';

                    elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') !== FALSE)
                            $browser = 'chrome';

                            else
                                    $browser = 'Something else'; 

    include $browser.'.php';

    ?>
```

Currently, I'm sending people to the browser styled page.. however I'm wanting to go a little more in-depth and target their versions, for example: FireFox 3.6 - 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use '[get_browser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)', it looks perfect for what you need.

Here is a concept example:

```
<?php

$user=get_browser(null,true)

if($user['browser'] == 'Firefox')
{
    if($user['version'] == '2.0')
    {
        if($user['platform'] == 'Linux')
        ...
    }
}

?>
```

See the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the version from $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] as well.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox/18') !== FALSE)
{
    $browser = 'firefox';
    $version = '18';
}
```